# How to insert to pivot table

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am trying to track Semi-private tennis lesson records using Laravel 5.3 and mysql. I am attempting to follow the example set in the Laravel 5 Many to Many tutorial. I have a Players model that I am trying to sync with a Sharedlessonhours table via a Player_Sharedlessonhours pivot table. In the code my sharedlessonhours table gets an inserted record, but the pivot table does not. Sorry to be so verbose, but I want to be clear about what's happening.

First the table structure.

```
     public function up()
{
    Schema::create('sharedlessonhours', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->date('signup_date');
        $table->integer('packages_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();


    });

     Schema::table('sharedlessonhours', function (Blueprint $table) {
         $table->foreign('packages_id')->references('id')->on('packages');
     });


    Schema::create('player_sharedlessonhour', function (Blueprint $table) 
    {
        $table->integer('sharedlessonhours_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('players_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();


    });

    Schema::table('player_sharedlessonhour', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('sharedlessonhours_id')->references('id')->on('sharedlessonhours')->onDelete('cascade');
          $table->foreign('players_id')->references('id')->on('players')->onDelete('cascade');

     });
}
```

The create and store methods:

```
    public function createSharedLessonhours()
{
    $players = Players::orderBy('lname')->pluck('fname', 'id');
    $packages = Packages::orderBy('name')->pluck('name','id');
    return view('admin.lessonhours.sharedlessonhours', compact('players', 'packages'));
}

public function storeSharedLessonhours(Request $request)
{
   $sharedlessonhours = SharedLessonhours::create($request->all());

   $sharedlessonhours->players()->attach($request->input('players'));
}
```

The Form:

```
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-5">
    {!! Form::open(['url' => 'sharedlessonhours']) !!}
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('players', 'Player(s):') !!}
        {!! Form::select('players[]', $players, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'multiple']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('signup_date', 'Signup Date:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('signup_date', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('packages_id', 'Lesson Package:') !!}
        {!! Form::select('packages_id', $packages, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Choose Package']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::submit('Signup', ['class' => 'btn btn-default form-control']) !!}
    </div>

{!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```

The screenshot of the select box for the player ids:
[image: Screenshot of select box]

And screenshot for error:
[image: SQLError Screenshot]

I am wondering if the array is simply in the incorrect order? dd($request) shows that everything is being collected from the form and but looking at the error page seems like it is trying to insert data into the wrong fields. The line that has (3,4) wouldn't be the correct order if that matters to mysql. I tried flipping the columns in mysql, but it didn't help. 
I am very confused right now.

UPDATE:
First I will share the requested code then share further steps I have taken to debug.

Players model code:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Collective\Html\Eloquent\FormAccessible;
use Carbon\Carbon;


class Players extends Model
{
    public $table = "players";

    protected $fillable = array('fname', 'lname', 'gender', 'birthdate');


    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'users_id');
    }

    public function lessonHours()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Lessonhours', 'players_id');
    }

    public function sharedlessonhours()
    {
             return $this->belongsToMany('App\SharedLessonhours',            "player_sharedlessonhour","players_id", "sharedlessonhours_id" );
    }

    public function getFullName($id)
    {
        return ucfirst($this->fname ) . ' ' . ucfirst($this->lname);
    }

    protected $dates = ['birthdate'];

    public function setBirthdateAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['birthdate'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y',     $value);
    }
}
```

SharedLessonhours:

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Collective\Html\Eloquent\FormAccessible;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class SharedLessonhours extends Model
{
    use FormAccessible;

    protected $fillable = array('signup_date', 'packages_id');

    public $table = "sharedlessonhours";

    public function players()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Players',     "player_sharedlessonhour", "players_id", "sharedlessonhours_id");
    }

    public function sharedhoursused()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\SharedHoursused', 'id');
    }

    public function packages()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Packages');
    }

    public function setSignUpDateAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['signup_date'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y',     $value);
    }
}
```

I attempted to add a different record after changing the columns in mysql       and get the error again. I switched the columns back and the error continues, eve`n after restarting tinker.

[image: tinker screenshot]

[image]

Comment: Can you try and hard code the player IDs for debugging (in the attach call). I couldn't spot any issues from the code provided.

Comment: You haven't provided the SharedLessonhours class, specifically the players() method, perhaps the issues lies there

Comment: Can you please post the contents of Player model as well as signatures of relationship in SharedLessonhours model?

Comment: I apologize, but I am struggling to update my question as the editor keeps throwing a wrong format error when I paste the code.

Comment: It was crazy trying to update the post. I had to indent manually using the space bar, save, then repeat. In the end, I hope this update makes sense to everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In addition to customizing the name of the joining table, you may also customize the column names of the keys on the table by passing additional arguments to the belongsToMany method. The third argument is the foreign key name of the model on which you are defining the relationship, while the fourth argument is the foreign key name of the model that you are joining to

From laravel documentation for Many-To-Many relationship.

Accordingly the definition of `players` relationship in your `SharedLessonhour` model should be as

```
public function players()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Players',  "player_sharedlessonhour", "sharedlessonhours_id",  "players_id");
}
```

Try changing the definition and see. I haven't tested but this seems to be the cause for constraint violation.